# ESLint Error in Example Code for Delete Collections from Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, eslint

In the function 'deleteQueryBatch' in the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data),

```
exports.batchDelete = function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) 
{
  query.get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        // When there are no documents left, we are done
        if (snapshot.size == 0) {
          return 0;
        }

    // Delete documents in a batch
    var batch = db.batch();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

    return batch.commit().then(() => {
      return snapshot.size;
    });
  }).then((numDeleted) => {
    if (numDeleted === 0) {
      resolve();
      return;
    }

    // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
    // exploding the stack.
    process.nextTick(() => {
      deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
    });
  })
  .catch(reject);
}
```

I can see the following ESLint Errors and Warnings.

```
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='. (eqeqeq)
Avoid nesting promises. (promise/no-nesting)
Each then() should return a value or throw (promise/always-return)
```

I got rid of the first error by replacing the referenced operator, however I'm not sure on how to address the other two.

Comment: What is the db parameter? A Firebase database?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec 
var db = admin.firestore(); from the docs

Answer (score 0):

A bit of info before solving the errors:

1. Avoid nesting promises. (promise/no-nesting) [Documentation](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/no-nesting.md)

   This can be fixed by concatenating the promises instead of calling one inside the other.
2. Each then() should return a value or throw (promise/always-return) [Documentation](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/always-return.md)

   This is a bit trickier, but it forces your promise to always return something

Answer:

```
function deleteSelectedDocuments(db, snapshot) {
    var deferred= new Promise();
    if (snapshot.size == 0) {
        deferred.resolve(snapshot);
    }

    // Delete documents in a batch
    var batch = db.batch();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        batch.delete(doc.ref);
    });

  batch.commit()
      .then(() => deferred.resolve(snapshot))
      .catch(() => deferred.reject());

  return deferred;
}

exports.batchDelete = function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
    query.get()
        .then((snapshot) => deleteSelectedDocuments(db, snapshot))
        .then((snapshot) => {
            // Solving rule error 1: Set numDeleted from the returned value of batch.commit.
            var numDeleted = snapshot.size;
            if (numDeleted === 0) {
                // Solving rule error 2: Return the resolve method (which resolves the upper promise?)
                return resolve();
            }

            process.nextTick(() => {
                deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
            });
            // Solving rule error 2: Return the resolve method (which resolves the upper promise?)
            return resolve();
        })
        .catch(reject);
}
```

If one or both rules doesn't fit for your code, you could just disable them.

Comment: batch.commit(); returns Promise<WriteResult[]> not a Promise<DocumentSnapshot>. Won't snapshot be out of scope or undefined in this case?

Comment: Damn you're right, I've updated my answer by wrapping the document deletion into a separated method, which would return the snapshot once it has been updated.
Please let me know how it goes. :)